# jsonb PostgreSQL условие по элементам массива

Tags: postgresql, nosql, jsonb

Всем привет!
Использую PostgreSQL 15.
Есть таблица типа:

```
game (тип text)    |   data (тип jsonb)
----------------------------------------
game1              |   {"PRODUCTION_CATEGORY": ["AAA"],"COMPLETIONLIST_HOURS": [22]}
game2              |   {"PRODUCTION_CATEGORY": ["AA"],"COMPLETIONLIST_HOURS": [21]}
game3              |   {"PRODUCTION_CATEGORY": ["Indie"],"COMPLETIONLIST_HOURS": [22]}
```

мне нужно получить из нее значения колонки game, где в data->PRODUCTION_CATEGORY встречается "AAA"

Делаю вот такой запрос:

```
select anket.game::text from anket cross join jsonb_array_elements(data ->'PRODUCTION_CATEGORY') as categ where categ='AAA'
```

В итоге PostgreSQL выдает ошибку:

> ERROR: ОШИБКА:  неверный синтаксис для типа json LINE 2: where
> categ='AAA' DETAIL:  Ошибочный элемент текста "AAA". CONTEXT:  данные
> JSON, строка 1: AAA SQL state: 22P02 Character: 119

Не могу взять в толк, что ему не нравится!
При этом если убрать условие where, то выводится нормально таблица в соответствии с командой cross join в запросе.

Помогите пожалуйста!